# How do I know when a new IBM DB2 Express-C version is released?

Tags: db2

How do I know when a new IBM DB2 Express-C version (or security patch) is released? Please, don't suggest following [#db2luw](https://twitter.com/hashtag/db2luw?f=live)... :)

**Update:**

According to [this page](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-version-111-mod-3-fix-pack-3-linux-unix-and-windows) security patches (called "fix packs") can not be applied with Express-C:

> DB2 fix packs can not be used with the Free version of DB2 Express-C. If you purchase the optional 12 Months Subscription license (also known as the Fixed Term License or FTL) you will be able to use DB2 Express with the FTL license and will be able to install the regular fix packs (Universal fix pack or Server fix pack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB2 Express-C has been withdrawn, so this question is no longer relevant.

It has been replaced by Db2 11.5 Community License Edition.

Comment: Can DB2 fix packs be used with DB2 Community License Edition?

Comment: @haba713 Yes, when Fixpacks / Modpacks are released, you will be able to apply them.

Comment: [DB2 @ Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Db2_Database#Updates): "Db2 Community edition is unsupported and regular Db2 fix packs can not be applied to it." Is it true?

Comment: @haba713 It’s true that you can’t call IBM for support, but you CAN apply fixpacks when they are released.